# Python openpyxl - Is it possible to edit an Excel file with openpyxl and KEEP the charts style? (mines become white)

Tags: python, excel, graph, openpyxl

I'd like basically to write data in an Excel sheet, in a table, with openpyxl. For this no problem, I achieved to do it.
The issue is: when I save the file (with the openpyxl save() function), and then when I open it manually, all the charts/graphs from the other sheets (that I haven't even touched) have now a white background/style. Cf. the screenshot below:

[Screenshot of the resultant chart on Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abyeo.png)

I've written some data in a Worksheet of my Excel file with openpyxl. Basically these data are filled in a table in an isolated sheet, and then the other sheets of my file draw graphs depending on these data.
So what I do is:

1. I get my data from a CSV file with a pandas DataFrame
2. I use openpyxl WorkBook and WorkSheet to write my data in the sheet I want, in my result XLSX file
3. I use the save() function of the openpyxl WorkBook to save my data

When I open manually my freshly modified XLSX file, the graphs are well updated, but have now the white background as shown before.

Does someon know if it's possible to keep the original style (originally it had a black/gray background) please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is still a possibility with Openpyxl. See the docs https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html and read the warning about 1/2 way down. Warning openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are opened and saved with the same name.